# CardView default background color problematic

Tags: android, colors, android-cardview

The default white background of `CardView` is problematic or am I missing something? When I fill the `CardView` with normal unstyled Android UI the white text of `TextView` is not readable e.g.

**Has someone an idea what a good fix for that would be?** I use the default "Theme.AppCompat" theme and the other background colors look correct. Is that a missing attribute in the Theme.AppCompat? Or am I doing something wrong? The default colors without setting any values manually should be always working or not?

**Edit:**

I now apply the default background color for the current style to the cardview like this:

```
    TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
            new int[] { android.R.attr.colorBackground });
    card.setCardBackgroundColor(array.getColor(0, 0xFF00FF));
```

I think its a quite save "default" fix to have at least no text color problems like in the screenshot but the question remains what should be the best practice here and why the cardview has alsways white as the default background color no matter what theme is used..

[image: Screenshot from Android 4.4 device]

Comment: As much of other things in Android CradView is filled with bugs. But if you want to take a closer look take a llok at source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/LayoutInflater.java, specifically method initialize(). There you will see that it should select light or dark color for background based on theme background. Yet... it does not. Welcome to the shitty collection of bugs... I mean android.

Comment: change the background color of layout in which your cardview is..

Answer (score -1):

By this way you can change Cardview background color,

```
    RoundRectDrawable backgroundDrawable = new RoundRectDrawable(backgroundColor, cardView.getRadius()); 
cardView.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundDrawable);
```

Comment: Better use card.setCardBackgroundColor(color) ;) But thats not a good solution to the default bahaviour I think. The default color of the CardView should be the opposite of the default text color, at least thats what I would expect.

Comment: don't do it, use the new API that lets you set the background color. Calling it will crash cardview before Lollipop.